# filebeat @timestamp not overwritten

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I use `filebeat` to write logs to an `elasticsearch` server. My logs are in json format. Every line is a json string that looks like this

```
{"@timestamp": "2017-04-11T07:52:480,230", "user_id": "1", "delay": 12}
```

I want the `@timestamp` field from my logs to replace the `@timestamp` field that filebeat creates when reading the logs. On my kibana dashboard I always get

> json_error:@timestamp not overwritten (parse error on 2017-04-11T07:52:48,230)

and end up seeing the `@timestamp` field created by filebeat

My filebeat conf includes those lines regarding overwriting fields

```
json.keys_under_root: true
json.overwrite_keys: true
json.add_error_key: true
```

Also from my `log4j` conf the `@timestamp` field created in my logs is in `ISO8601` format. Any idea what the problem is and why the `@timestamp` field is not overwritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the format of the timestamp that `log4j` is producing.
Filebeat expects something of the form `"2017-04-11T09:38:33.365Z"` it has to have to `T` in the middle the `Z` in the end and dot instead of comma before the milliseconds.

Quickest (and somewhat dirty) way I found to do that was by using the following pattern

```
pattern='{"@timestamp": "%d{YYYY-MM-dd}T%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}Z"}
```

A similar issue can be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1246). The suggested solution does not solve the filebeat issue though because it uses comma!